# Blazor - how to make only one input check box of two to return value as true

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

I have two check boxes like this:

```
<EditForm Model="Advert" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit">
<label>true</label> <InputCheckbox class="form-control" @bind-Value="@Advert.BuSe"/>
<label>false</label> <InputCheckbox class="form-control" @bind-Value="@Advert.BuSe"/>
<EditForm>
```

Checkboxes can return true/false. So if the first is selected, I want **@Advert.BuSe** value to be true and If the second check box is selected I want it to be false.However, now both are linked to each other due to binding.

It is important for me that I can display two check boxes without any visual drop-downs. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need two checkboxes for true or false value of a single property? Bind the property to one checkbox, if it's checked it's true, otherwise it's false.

Comment: @insane_developer then I need to force user select one of two, how could I do that? it is like answer to question yes/no, user has to select yes or no

Comment: I would use a dropdown where the default is something like "Please choose one option". This is very common. Radio buttons are also common for this type of scenario (mutually exclusive selections), although there is usually a default selection. Checkboxes are more appropriate for multiple selection use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="@advert.BuSe"  @onchange="@((args) => { advert.BuSe = screen =  (bool) args.Value; } )" />

<input type="checkbox" checked="@advert.BuSe" @onchange="@((args) => { advert.BuSe = screen =  false; } )" />

<div>@screen.ToString()</div>
@code {
    private bool screen;
    private Advert advert = new Advert();

    public class Advert
    {
        public bool BuSe { get; set; }
    }
}
```